# Authorize attribute is not working in JWT and asp.net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt

I have implemented JWT for .net core client but when I put authorize attribute its gives me 401 unauthorized response every time.
    I have try to mentioned schema name within attribute.Changes sequence of middle ware. gone through plenty of links from stack overflow.

**Below is startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddSwaggerDocumentation();

        services.ConfigureCors();

        services.ConfigureIISIntegration();

        services.ConfigureLoggerService();

        services.ConfigureSqlContext(Configuration);

        services.ConfigureRepositoryWrapper();

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:5000",
                ValidAudience = "http://localhost:4200/",
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superSecretKey@345"))
            };
        });

        services.AddMvc();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerManager logger)
    {

        app.UseSwaggerDocumentation();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();                
        }

        app.UseHttpStatusCodeExceptionMiddleware();

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All
        });

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();

            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404
                && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                await next();
            }
        });


        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

> Below is code of JWT initialization

```
if (userInfo.Any(c => c.ValidUser == "Y"))
                    {
                        var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superSecretKey@345"));

                        var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                        var claims = new List<Claim>
                            {
                                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, vsecGetPasswordByUserName.LoginId),
                                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
                            };

                        var tokeOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
                            issuer: "http://localhost:5000",
                            audience: "http://localhost:4200",
                            claims: claims,
                            expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5),
                            signingCredentials: signinCredentials
                        );

                        var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokeOptions);

                        return Ok(new { UserInfo = userInfo, TokenString = tokenString });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new HttpStatusCodeException(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized, @"User not valid");
                    }
                }
```

and this is controller code where authorize attribute is mentioned

```
[Authorize]
[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/Utility")]
public class UtilityController : ControllerBase
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `UseAuthorization` middleware in the `Configure` method of the `Startup` class.

Put it as follows:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization(); // <-- Here it is
```

Comment: Not able to find this middle ware need to add any package for it?

Comment: Use `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;` namespace.

Comment: @TanvirArjel `app.UseAuthorization()` only applies to NET Core 3.0 and above as per [doco](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.authorizationappbuilderextensions.useauthorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1). The question targets NET Core 2.1

Comment: not able to find under this namespace or Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention to your `TokenValidationParameters`, your `audience` is `http://localhost:4200/` , which is not match the one(`http://localhost:4200`) in token claims :

So just modify the `ValidAudience` in `TokenValidationParameters` to  :

```
ValidAudience = "http://localhost:4200",
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion but it still same response. I am trying from swagger also.

Comment: Use Fiddler to trace the 401 and check whether any detailed error returned ,also  set schema name within attribute

Comment: I have modify JWT intialization

Comment: //services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
            //{
            //    auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            //        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            //        .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
            //});

            //services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            //{
            //    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            //    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            //}) and mentioned schema nam

Comment: what i mean is set  scheme with Authorize attribute ,and if still 401 , you can use fiddler or develop tools to trace the inner error message in `WWW-Authenticate` header of response

Comment: Bearer Token = "Invalid_Token"

Answer (score 0):

My token schema was
Bearer : {'Token' : 'Abcsdsdsgddcdsa'}

I have changes schema to

Bearer : 'Asdsaasadcaca'

And its working as expected